# Passing data between scenarioes in karate

Tags: karate

I have a requirement to pass the response of first web services to next service. We maintain one scenario for each web services. Some of the tags in first services needs to be passed to next web services within the feature file itself. Please help.

Thanks,
Thiyagu

Answer (score 0):

I think you have fundamentally misunderstood the way a `Scenario` works. Each `Scenario` is supposed to be independent. You can't have one `Scenario` update a variable and then expect that other ones can see the updated value. Please combine your 'flows' into one `Scenario`. Or if some 'setup' steps are common, use a `Background` section.

Keep in mind that you should be able to comment-out a `Scenario` or skip some via tags without impacting any others.